# Using WriteLineAsync in F#

Tags: f#, async-await

I am learning F# and I have problem with using WriteLineAsync.

With synchronous code it works perfectly:

```
using (new StreamWriter(new FileStream(@"c:\work\f2.txt",  FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize= 4096, useAsync= true)))
(fun sw -> File.ReadLines @"c:\Work\f1.txt" |> Seq.iter(fun x-> sw.WriteLine(x) ))
```

When I try to user WriteLineAsync:

```
using (new StreamWriter(new FileStream(@"c:\work\f2.txt",  FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize= 4096, useAsync= true)))
    (fun sw -> File.ReadLines @"c:\Work\f1.txt" |> Seq.iter(fun x-> sw.WriteLineAsync(x) |>  Async.AwaitTask |>  ignore ))
```

I got error InvalidOperationException:The stream writer is currently in use by a previous write operation.

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: How you can write/modify same file at same time. You are not doing right operation on file. syntax is fine.

Comment: It is not the same file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `AwaitTask` does is that it converts from `Task<T>` to `Async<T>`, it doesn't actually await anything. That means you can't just `ignore` the result.

What you can do is to create an `async` workflow and await `WriteLineAsync()` by using `do!`:

```
async {
    use sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(@"c:\work\f2.txt",  FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize= 4096, useAsync= true))
    for line in File.ReadLines @"c:\Work\f1.txt" do
        do! sw.WriteLineAsync(line) |>  Async.AwaitTask
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that.